# Django - Get response to return image without saving file to models

Tags: django, python-requests

I am using the [tmdb api](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3) to return movie info as well as images. 
Steps below of Get logic

1. Api request is made which provides movie info as well as "backdrop_path"
2. I then use this path to make another request for the jpg related to that movie.

**Blocker**
I'm unable to then output that jpg. It currently returns a url path as below.

[image]

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
import requests
import urllib
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
# Query API with user input 
    if 'movie' in request.GET:
        api_key = 'api'
        id = request.GET['movie']
        url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key={}&language=en-US&query={}&include_adult=false'
        response = requests.get(url.format(api_key,id))


         
        
        # successful request
        if response.status_code == 200:

            # Parse json output for key value pairs 
            tmdb = response.json()
            
            # save image jpg 
            backdrop_path = tmdb['results'][0]['backdrop_path']
            url = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/{}'
            gg = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url.format(backdrop_path), 'test.jpg')        

            context = {
                'title': tmdb['results'][0]['original_title'],
                'overview': tmdb['results'][0]['overview'],
                'release_date': tmdb['results'][0]['release_date'],
                'vote_average': tmdb['results'][0]['vote_average'],
                'vote_count': tmdb['results'][0]['vote_count'],
                'backdrop_path' : tmdb['results'][0]['backdrop_path'],
                'jpg' : gg
                }
            



            return render(request, 'home.html', {'context': context}) 
        

        else: # returns homepage if invalid request
                return render(request, 'home.html')

    else: # Homepage without GET request
        return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urlretrieve` doesn't return the image ready to be used, instead it returns a tuple with the local name of the file and the headers (as an HTTPMessage object as you can see in your example), which is what you're seeing.

However, I don't think returning a file in your response is ideal, nor it would work in your scenario. Since you seem to be using templates, what I would do is return the image url and use it in an image HTML tag, like this `<img src="{{ jpg }}"/>`